# Close Android application via Browsable intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I created an app that can only be opened via link in the browser. However, I need that app to be closed from the browser too. I managed to pass parameters to the intent so I can decide whether to close or open the app. I placed some log debug in the code and this is the logcat output when I open it

```
07-10 15:06:52.383  20718-20718/xx.yy.,mypp D/MAIN﹕ ONCREATE
07-10 15:06:52.385  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/PARAMS﹕ add
07-10 15:06:52.385  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/PARAMS﹕ START
07-10 15:06:52.385  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ READING PARAMS
07-10 15:06:52.386  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x1c/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x106000d}
07-10 15:06:52.388  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ START
07-10 15:06:52.388  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ startCameraService
07-10 15:06:52.388  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ Floating camera OFF
07-10 15:06:52.388  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ Starting service
07-10 15:06:52.394  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ Floating camera ACTIVE
```

And everything seems to work fine. then I click in the other link to close it and the Logcat shows:

```
07-10 15:07:02.176  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ ONCREATE
07-10 15:07:02.181  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/PARAMS﹕ del
07-10 15:07:02.188  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/PARAMS﹕ CLOSE
07-10 15:07:02.188  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ READING PARAMS
07-10 15:07:02.194  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp W/Resources﹕ Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x1c/d=0x0 a=1 r=0x106000d}
07-10 15:07:02.195  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ STOP
07-10 15:07:02.195  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ stopCameraService
07-10 15:07:02.204  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ Floating camera OFF
07-10 15:07:02.264  20718-20718/xx.yy.myapp D/MAIN﹕ DESTROY!!!
```

But the app is still open. This is the code of the MainActivity:

```
package xx.yy.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Intent cameraService = null;
    private boolean actionStart = true;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.shared_prefs), MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("MAIN", "ONCREATE");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        readParams();
        Log.d("MAIN", "READING PARAMS");
        if(actionStart) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getText(R.string.camera_starting), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.d("MAIN", "START");
            startCameraService();
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            onStateChange();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, getText(R.string.camera_closing), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Log.d("MAIN", "STOP");
            stopCameraService();
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.d("MAIN", "DESTROY!!!");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void readParams()
    {
        String cameraId = "";
        String quality = "medium";
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        String host = data.getHost();
        List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
        try {
            cameraId = params.get(1);
            Log.d("PARAMS", params.get(0));
            actionStart = params.get(0).compareTo("add")==0;
            quality = params.get(2);
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ibe)
        { /*sometimes quality param is not passed*/ }
        Log.d("PARAMS", actionStart?"START":"CLOSE");
        editor.putString("host", host);
        editor.putString("id", cameraId);
        editor.putString("quality", quality);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void startCameraService()
    {
        Log.d("MAIN", "startCameraService");
        if(!checkService())
        {
            Log.d("MAIN", "Starting service");
            this.cameraService = new Intent(this, FloatCamService.class);
            startService(this.cameraService);
            checkService();
        }
    }

    private void stopCameraService()
    {
        Log.d("MAIN", "stopCameraService");
        if(checkService()) {
            Log.d("MAIN", "Stopping service");
            stopService(this.cameraService);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkService()
    {
        editor.putBoolean("serviceStatus", (this.cameraService != null && startService(this.cameraService) != null)).apply();
        onStateChange();
        return getServiceStatus();
    }

    public void toggleCamera(View clickedView)
    {
        if(!getServiceStatus()) {
            this.startCameraService();
        }
        else
        {
            this.stopCameraService();
        }
    }

    public void openStreaming(View clickedView)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, StreamingActivity.class));
    }

    private boolean getServiceStatus()
    {
        return prefs.getBoolean("serviceStatus", false);
    }

    public void onStateChange() {
        if (getServiceStatus()) {
            Log.d("MAIN", getString(R.string.service_on));
        } else {
            Log.d("MAIN", getString(R.string.service_off));
        }
    }
}
```

The Service onDestroy method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    try {
        Log.d("XXXXXXXXXXXXX", (container != null)? "NULL":"NOT NULL");
        if (container != null) windowManager.removeView(container);
        camHead.stop();
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException iae)
    {

    }catch(NullPointerException npe)
    {
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Please define "the app is still open". What specifically do you mean by "open", and how did you determine whether or not it is "open"?

Comment: @CommonsWare basically the app with start a service that service create a floating view (like the ChatHead in Facebook). When I "close" the app the chat head is still there. but the call to stop service should destroy all of that.

Comment: "but the call to stop service should destroy all of that" -- then presumably there is a bug in your service code, where the service is not getting rid of the floating view in its `onDestroy()`.

Comment: Well I just put some Log.d in the service `onDestroy` and it doesn't seem to be called. Why is that? I added the onDestroy code in the question

Comment: Depending upon the state of the activity, `this.cameraService` will be `null`, as you have not necessarily initialized it. `Intent` objects are very inexpensive to create and hold. I recommend creating a new one at each usage, rather than bothering to cache it. However, if `this.cameraService` were `null`, I would expect you to crash with a `NullPointerException` or some other problem. You also should check your `checkService()` behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. The app only starts the service, nothing more. How can I make the code work? I can't figure it out.